# Get list of email and select top email with desired title/subject and click it

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automated a password recovery onto my test script.
I am trying to get the email from malinator.com, and this is what it looks like.

```
<li class="row-fluid message ng-scope" ng-repeat="email in emails">
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="showmail('1411426607-6188591-xapncvfk501')">
<div class="from ng-binding" style="width:223px;float:left;"> Mentor Support </div>
<div class="subject ng-binding" style="width:473px;float: left;"> Recovered Password </div>
<div class="time ng-binding" style="text-align: right;float:left;width:144px;padding: 0 5px 0 5px;margin:0;"> 16 minutes ago </div>
</a>
</li>
<li class="row-fluid message ng-scope" ng-repeat="email in emails">
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="showmail('1411426524-6185292-xapncvfk501')">
<div class="from ng-binding" style="width:223px;float:left;"> Mentor Support </div>
<div class="subject ng-binding" style="width:473px;float: left;"> Recovered Password </div>
<div class="time ng-binding" style="text-align: right;float:left;width:144px;padding: 0 5px 0 5px;margin:0;"> 18 minutes ago </div>
```

Here is my code:

```
IWebElement  container = driver.FindElement(By.Id("mailcontainer"));
            IList<IWebElement> emails = container.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[class$='ng-binding']"));
            string[] title = new string[emails.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < title.Length; i++)
            {
                title[i] = emails[i].Text;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < title.Length; i++)
            {
                if (title[i].Contains("Mentor Support"))
                {
                    return i.ToString();
                }
                driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(title[i])).Click();
            }
```

What i am trying to do is grab the email list and whichever email contains the 'Recovered Password' or Mentor Support title, then to click on the topmost from the list. I know my second for statement is the one giving me problems and im not sure if I am calling it correctly.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely avoid trying to automate 3rd party email website as part of your testing.

Using an email providers API to programmatically get and read the email is a much faster and stable solution.

Checkout this;

http://sellotapetest.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/page-objectswhy-not-email-objects.html?m=1